# Array reference type in a method

Tags: java, arrays, oop, multidimensional-array, methods

I have been given a starting code to work on a project, however I am confused about the following code and cant seem to find any examples online!

```
public static Entity[][] read(){ ... }
```

How can I handle this Entity to add new entries to an array, and then how can I return this?

The following constructor is invoked by a different class.

```
public World() {
    aWorld = new Entity[SIZE][SIZE];
    int r;
    int c;
    for (r = 0; r < SIZE; r++) {
        for (c = 0; c < SIZE; c++) {
            aWorld[r][c] = null;
        }
    }
    aWorld = FileInitialization.read();
}
```

I feel it would be much simpler if the array was just a parameter or if it were something like:

```
public static int[][] read(){ ... }
```

UPDATE:

The goal is to read from a file in the method read() and then assign the an entity to the correct location based on the location in the file. But I am not able to assign since the data types would be incompatible, Required is Entity, but I want to be able to set it to an int, char or String.

Comment: It's a 2D array of type `Entity` (and not `int` as in your sample)

Comment: So what data type can I use to modify this array?

Comment: There are few pointless things in your code: (1) you are initializing array with `null` which is already done by default, (2) you are reassigning `aWorld` array you earlier created with new array returned from `FileInitialization.read` which makes first part of constructors code pointless.

Comment: `Entity` **is** the type.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not allowed to modify this code, as that is one of the requirements, probably the professor has a background in a different language as the reason he makes the initialization? Second part is probably for him to teach us oop.

Comment: This is really strange code to be provided with (mainly because of @Pshemo 's second point and possibly of `aWorld` reading in with dimensions not described by `SIZE`). Perhaps a careful review of the code or instructions may unearth something. Hard to image the goal is teaching good OOP.

Comment: You need to show the Entity class and the input file format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I would like to say thanks to all of you here as I was set on the right direction. But I would like to share my answer which should be simple and hopefully make someones life easier in the future.

To initialize the array of objects just do it as you would initialize any other array, in this case:

```
Entity[][] reference_name = new Entity[SIZE][SIZE];
```

To return this value, simply return the reference:

```
return reference_name;
```

Now the part where you actually modify an entry into your array.
Lets say you have something like

```
public static void Entity[][] read() { .. }
```

you need to create a class file Entity.java (same name as the array type being passed)

In this case it would look something like this:

```
public class Entity {
private char appearance;

public Entity(char anAppearance) {

    appearance = anAppearance;
}
```

now to give this array an entry do something like this:

```
reference_name[0][0] = new Entity('X');
```

alright and in case you are wondering how to display this just add an accesor method to class Entity.

```
public char getAppearance() {

    return(appearance);
}
```

and to output:

```
System.out.println(reference_name[0][0].getAppearance(); );
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to an array of objects, you do exactly what you would with an array of primitives (e.g. `int`s), you just use `Entity`s. So if you want to add something to `aWorld` you use

```
aWorld[r][c] = new Entity(...); //with provided constructor's parameters
// or
aWorld[r][c] = existing_Entity; //for an Entity variable you already have
```

When you're done adding, you simply return the array `aWorld`.

Comment: Thanks! I am on the right track but one thing I don't understand is that when I try to make an entry into the array I get an error incompatible types, "Required: Entity, Found: int" am I suppose to cast somehow?

Comment: @user3170899  No, an `Entity[][]` is an array of `Entity` objects. Why would want to put an `int` in it?

Answer (score 0):

If FileInitialization's static read() is going to return Entity[][], that's an entity array by itself. It means that you shouldn't iterate aWorld, rather assign the return value to it directly like

aWorld = FileInitialization.read();

Inside the read(), use that for loop you've made in the constructor and add a new Entity object as noted by Linus